# Search for documents by key using Domino Data Service

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Domino Data Service is a good thing but is it possible to search for documents by key.
I didnt find anything in the api and the url parameters about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like the following:

```
GET http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/documents?search=QUERY&searchmaxdocs=N
```

N would be the total number of documents to return and QUERY would be your search phrase. The QUERY would be the same as doing a full text search.

For column lookups it should be something like this:

```
GET http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/documents?sortcolumn=COLUMN&sortorder=ascending&keys=ROWVALUE&keysexactmatch=true
```

COLUMN would be the column name. ROWVALUE would be the key you are looking for.

There are further options for this. More details here.

http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#migratingtowebsphereportalversion7.0

Comment: The parameters you describe in the second URI are not valid for that API - see: [Document collection](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_ref_documentcollection):
GET http://{host}/{database}/api/data/documents?{parameters}

Comment: That post is from 3 years ago. DDS may have changed since.

Comment: I looked into this quite deeply and found that it hasn't changed: in the /documents API there's no view mentioned, so there's no notion of a column. Which column in whcih view woul it use ?

Comment: If you want to get a document's content, you have to access it by its UNID or I thinnk NoteId, you can't get it via a key in the view. If yo do that, you can only get the view columns back. It'd be a delight if you could get the whole doc via a view though, that would have saved me writing an agent to do just that

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above and the requests usually fail on the server timeout after 30 seconds. Calls to `/api/data/documents` won't serve the purpose with parameters like `sortcolumn` or `keysexactmatch`, therefore calls to
  `/api/data/collections` should be used for these.
Also, I don't think that arguments like `sortcolumn` would work on a document collection, because there isn't a column to be sorted in the first place, columns are in the views and not in documents, so view collection should be queried instead. That also mimics the behavior of `getDocumentByKey` method, which can't be called against document, but against the view. So instead:

```
http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/documents?search=QUERY&searchmaxdocs=N
```

I would call

```
http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/collections/name/viewname?search=QUERY&searchmaxdocs=N
```

and instead of

```
http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/documents?sortcolumn=COLUMN&sortorder=ascending&keys=ROWVALUE&keysexactmatch=true
```

I would call:

```
http://HOSTNAME/DATABASE.nsf/api/data/collections/name/viewname?sortcolumn=COLUMN&sortorder=ascending&keys=ROWVALUE&keysexactmatch=true
```

where 'viewname' is the name of the view that is searched.
That is much faster, which comes in handy when working with larger databases.

Comment: I would appreciate knowing the reason for downvoting. Thanks